# Filter Documents "Max(x) on Group(y)"

Tags: sharepoint

I have following metadata in a SharePoint library:

```
Category   Revision  ...
   A01        1      ...
   A01        2      ...
   A01        3      ...
   A02        1      ...
   A03        1      ...
   A03        2      ...
```

Is it possible (question: how) to configure a filter "max(Revision) on GroupBy(Category)?
The outcome should be:

```
Category   Revision  ...
   A01        3      ...
   A02        1      ...
   A03        2      ...
```

I need the highest Revision per Category.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this from client side script, similar thread [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/585e434c-7f06-4e2e-9893-37f5330dad82/year-wise-sum-for-top-10-scores-using-script-editor?forum=sharepointdevelopment#6151d7c6-279d-4e14-b275-996299fee097).

Key logic:

```
var sorted = groupBy(top5Items, function (item) {
                return [item.Credits];
            });
            //var groupedResult = groupBy(top5Items, 'Credits');

            $.each(sorted, function (key, value) {
                var userNames='';
                var userCredits=0;
                $.each(value, function (index, sItem) {
                    if (index > 0) {
                        userNames += ',' + sItem.User;
                    } else {
                        userCredits = sItem.Credits;
                        userNames += sItem.User;
                    }
                })
                $('#example>tbody').append('<tr><td>' + userNames + '</td><td>' + userCredits + '</td></tr>');                
            })

function groupBy(array, f) {
            var groups = {};
            array.forEach(function (o) {
                var group = JSON.stringify(f(o));
                groups[group] = groups[group] || [];
                groups[group].push(o);
            });
            return Object.keys(groups).map(function (group) {
                return groups[group];
            });
        }
```